# Почему не передаются данные в контроллер ASP MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Возникает странная проблема, которые я даже незнаю как решишь.

Во View у меня есть поле, которое заполняется ajax запросом, при выборе выпадающем меню компании

```
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <span class="control-label col-sm-3">Выберите компанию</span>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CompanyId, ViewBag.SelectedCompanies as SelectList, "Выберите компанию", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "companies" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


<div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Ue_inv_number, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-3" })
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Ue_inv_number, new { @class = "form-control required", @id = "inv_num" })
                    <div>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Ue_inv_number)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Делается запрос, вот код jquery запроса

```
function invent() {
    $("#inv_num").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#companies").change(function () {
        if ($("#companies").val() != "") {
            var options = {};
            options.url = "/Uchet/GetInventNumber";
            options.type = "POST";
            options.data = JSON.stringify({ company: $("#companies").val() });
            options.dataType = "json";
            options.contentType = "application/json";
            options.success = function (company) {
                $("#inv_num").empty();
                for (var i = 0; i < company.length; i++) {
                    $("#inv_num").val(company[i].Short_Name + company[i].id_num);

                }

            };

            $.ajax(options);
        }
        else if ($("#companies").val() == "") {
            $("#inv_num").val("");
            $("#inv_num").prop("disabled", true);
        }

    }
        )};
```

В контроллере все выглядит так

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetInventNumber(int company)
{

    int id_num;
    try
    {
        id_num = (from ue in db.Ue
                       orderby ue.Id descending
                       select ue.Id).First();
        id_num++;
    }
    catch
    {
        id_num = 0;
    }
    var result_list = from c in db.Ue_companies.Where(x => x.Id == company)
                      select new { c.Short_Name, id_num };
    return Json(result_list);
}
```

Все ок. поле заполняется внизу Инвент. номер.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дальше при нажатии кнопки создать, возникает проблема. Ставлю точку остоновы, на контроллере, который принимает модель. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть ,что это поле заполнено он не видит! Не могу объяснить почему. Скорее всего потому-что оно заполняется с помощью ajax запроса? Как мне решить эту проблему?

Нашел решение все дело  `$("#inv_num").prop("disabled", true);` убрал это с запроса и данные передаются

То есть ты выставляешь это свойство полю, то оно отключено и  теперь какие бы ты данные туда не выводил, их по сути там нет. Может кто-то объяснит почему ?

Comment: У меня вопрос небольшой. Вы привели код метода `GetInventNumber`, а скрин приложили другого метода. Как это понять?

Comment: Можете выложить код, который отправляет форму?

Comment: Там просто кнопка submit и все

Answer (score 3, accepted):

содержание disabled полей формы не включаются браузером в пост запрос. 
чтобы предотвратить редактирование поля, вам необходимо использовать не `disabled` а `readonly` аттрибут.